NSLog wrapper in Objective-C not working in Swift
I am working on a project in which I have added an SDK using pod. There are some logs within the SDK code they have added using NSLog wrapper as:
#define LogDebug(message, ...) { \
    [LogObjcWrapper logDebug:[NSString stringWithFormat: message, ##__VA_ARGS__] file:@__FILE__ function:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __FUNCTION__] line:__LINE__]; \
}

I want the logs, printed using above wrapper, in my project debug console in Xcode. I am not sure how to get that logs.
Eg. that I want to get in the debug console is :

LogDebug(@"[FileModule.m] removeExtraFilesFromCount: %@. removeItemAtPath: %@\n", @(count), <fiel_path>);

Here the FileModule.m is a file from SDK in which the SDK developer have added the code as above to show the log. I want to retrieve that log, which currently I am not able to get.
Expected Output:

"[FileModule.m] removeExtraFilesFromCount: 0. removeItemAtPath: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..."

SDK is Developed in Objective-C. I am using Xcode 15.2 on macOS 14.4.1. The wift version in my app is Swift 5.

Wouldn't you use LogObjcWrapper directly?

@trojanfoe, this code is from SDK. And I want to get the logs which they use to print using "LogDebug". I don't want to change any code from SDK.

They use LogDebug in Swift code?  I don't see how.

The SDK is developed in Objective-C. I am using Swift in which I want the logs of SDK. I hope I make my self clear.

OK so if you must use LogDebug etc. then you will need to create those functions yourself, which mimic what the macros do.  Otherwise use LogObjcWrapper directly.

@trojanfoe, I have updated my question which might help you to get clear idea about my requirements

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

OK so my understanding is that Xcode 15 no longer redirects stderr to its debug console; instead it gets the entries from the system log.  So you are best to use os_log to write your log messages and ignore those macros.

You need read that SDK's documentation and find out how to enable longs in it. As we doesn't know which library you are using, we can't help you.
